# Unable to store data using POST request in django-rest API

Tags: django-rest-framework

Disclaimer :- I am a beginner.
I am trying to build a Django REST API which can support all CRUD operations.
I am able to get the data from API call(127.0.0.1/api/get) and also able to add , modify and delete the record manually from the UI(after GET request).
I have created one form inside template directory which takes the input from user and on submit it goes to the same url (127.0.0.1/api/get) but data is not being saved, instead it is returning this :- 
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "sourceName": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "sourceURL": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}

I have only one app (source).
views.py :-

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from source import models
from source import serializers
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.views import APIView

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Forms/input.html')

class SourceViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    print("Inside ConnectionInfoViewset..")
    queryset = models.Source.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SourceSerializer
    print("Inside ConnectionInfoViewset..")

    def post(self,request):
        print("Inside POST")
        return JsonResponse("From POST", safe=False)
        serializer = serializers.SourceSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


source_urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from source import views
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('', views.SourceViewset)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('get/', include(router.urls)),
]

serializers.py:-

from rest_framework import serializers
from source import models
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

class SourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Source
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = ('sourceName','sourceURL')

models.py:- 

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Source(models.Model):
    sourceName =  models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    sourceURL = models.CharField(max_length = 40)    

def __str__(self):
    return self.__all__

input.html:- 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/api/get/"  method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" placeholder="SourceName" name = 'user_name'> <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="SourceURL" name = 'password'><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you tried this above code? Is it working or not?

Comment: Only GET method i am able to use. when I try to submit the HTML form data using POST It is giving:-  HTTP 400 Bad Request Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS Content-Type: application/json Vary: Accept

{ "sourceName": [ "This field is required." ], "sourceURL": [ "This field is required." ] }

Comment: Change the Html form fields name according to your models name. Both are mismatching

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sakthi. It is working now. One more favor please, as I have deleted the post method defined in view.py and still it is working so It is clearly not coming here. What changes should I make in HTML form in order to enable the PUT request  I tried this :-

Comment: <form action="/api/get/1/"  method = "">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" placeholder="SourceName" name = 'sourceName'> <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="SourceURL" name = 'sourceURL'><br>
        <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="SourceParameter" name="sourceParameter"> -->
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

Comment: but it is not giving any error and it is converting into GET request.

How to define the method to catch those GET,POST,PUT,DELETE requests to customize it. Thanks again.

Comment: Check the below answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how viewset is defined in DRF package, you can write your customized method code inside the respective blocks.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
"""
Example empty viewset demonstrating the standard
actions that will be handled by a router class.

If you're using format suffixes, make sure to also include
the `format=None` keyword argument for each action.
"""

def list(self, request):
    pass

def create(self, request):
    pass

def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    pass

def update(self, request, pk=None):
    pass

def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
    pass

def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
    pass
```

And one more things you can't use the same form to do PUT, you need to catch submit in ajax and call API. This is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SourceViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        print("inside list")
        queryset = models.Source.objects.all()
        serializer_class = serializers.SourceSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = serializers.SourceSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

You mean to implement custom GET and POST request handler it should look like this? for above example, as it is not working like this.Clearly i am missing something can you correct this example of GET and POST?